# Android how to delete application shortcut?

Tags: java, android

When I create a shortcut for my application, and when I want to delete shortcut with code, how should I do it? I try some method but not used.
The create shortcut code:

```
        Intent shortcut = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "test");
        shortcut.putExtra("duplicate", false);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setClass(this, SecondActivity.class);
        shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, intent);
        Intent.ShortcutIconResource iconRes = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconRes);
        sendBroadcast(shortcut);`
```

The delete shortcut code:

```
        actionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        actionIntent.setClass(this, SecondActivity.class);
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "taotao");
        intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, actionIntent);
        sendBroadcast(intent);`
```

Comment: Do you have this permission in manifest  "<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" /> " Also why is your EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME different.?

Comment: thank you, every thing you said ,I have already checked,no problem.

Comment: Then may be because you are using a third party launcher and the launcher doesn't have the permission to remove shortcuts ,then it won't work.

Comment: I think so,but  I use nexus 5 and native OS,   useless